# Applescript Illustrator Dialogs

Tags: applescript, adobe, dialog

I have an AppleScript that does stuff in Illustrator and saves the file and then does other stuff.

On almost every machine it works.

One oddball Mac (macOS 11.6.2 - Illustrator 26.0.2) machine the save line throws up a save dialog:

```
    tell application id "com.adobe.illustrator"
        save document 1 in POSIX file "Macintosh HD:Users:Shared:Output.pdf" as pdf with options {compatibility:Acrobat 5, preserve editability:true}
    end tell
```

Why are these dialogs showing up? How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Are the macOS and Illustrator versions the same?

Comment: Same versions of both.  There must be some flag or preference or something.